# UIScreen.main is now deprecated; what's the proper way to get screen width upfront?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following code:

```
            ZStack {
                AsyncImage(url: URL(string: url)) { image in
                    image
                } placeholder: {
                    EmptyView()
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                buttons
            }
```

The image extends off the screen, but this is something I want so I don't resize it. However, I have buttons in a ZStack on top of the image that pin to the corners of the view. Because the image extends past the screen, I need to limit the max width of the view the image is in so that the ZStack doesn't extend off the screen. I am using the UIScreen method right now which works, but Xcode is telling me UIScreen.main is deprecated. I can't use GeometryReader since I need to know the size up front, so what would be the best method to do this?

Comment: There are ways to work around this, but why the screen size? What if your app runs on split view, a resizable mac app, or different stages of future iPhones with multiple windows?
you should go with the geometry reader, even if you need it upfront. And don't forget that it is dynamic and may change at runtime

Comment: You can use .infinity in maxWidth

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini I have no clue what happened, I was playing around with so many different options with geometry reader yesterday and in all cases the space the geo reader was taking extended off the screen, but I just tried it again and it worked. I don't like using geometry reader because it oftentimes leads to odd behavior from it taking up all the space.

Answer (score -2):

You can use GeometryReader like this;

```
GeometryReader { geo in
   //Your code here
}
.frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
```

Comment: This won´t work. `geo` will only be accassible inside the closure.

Comment: @burnsi If you put your ZStack inside it, it will be available on the whole view.

Comment: That´s true. Still your code won´t compile cause you access `geo` outside of the closure.

Comment: It seems we are misunderstanding each other, if your code is in the closure, it will compile as long as it is on the view, you can try it.